# Override matched Line

Tags: shell, awk, ffmpeg

When I print the output from ffmpeg to a file, I get something like this:

```
[...]
frame=   28 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=N/A speed=2.31x    
frame=   55 fps= 54 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.24 bitrate=N/A speed= 2.2x    
frame=   84 fps= 55 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.40 bitrate=N/A speed=2.22x    
frame=  112 fps= 54 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.52 bitrate=N/A speed=2.17x    
[...]
```

Now I would like that all lines that matches with `frame=*` get replaced and only the last current line get printed to the text file (in real time).

Is this possible?

At the moment I have this line:

`ffmpeg -v info -i input.ext -f null 2>&1 | awk '/frame=/{gsub(/.*/, $0)};{print}'`

It works almost, except that all line with contain `frame=*` are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate the file from within awk and write to it once per line, like this:

```
awk '/frame=/ { close("file"); print > "file" }'
```

When you use `>` in awk, it opens and truncates the file before writing to it. Subsequent writes to the same file are appended. If you close the file each time, then it will always truncate it next time it writes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter:

```
awk '/frame=/{f=$0; next}END{print f}'
```

It saves the latest line matching `frame=` in `f` without printing it, and prints the saved value at the end of the script.

Comment: Thank you Michael, the problem with this is, that I get the result when ffmpeg is done with the process. But I need the output already while ffmpeg is running, so I can capture the log file in real time.